# How to Change File Upload Path in Voyager

Tags: laravel, voyager

I have a application created using Laravel and Voyager Admin Panel when I run my application on localhost voyager uploaded image save in project/public/storage but when I deploye my Project to shared hosting voyager files uploading to project/storage/app/public so how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then change your file system as below:

```
your-app-root-dir/config/filesystems.php
```

replace the first file ecosystem `local` to `public`
and then below down change your public disk URL location to `storage/app/public` or whatever you want.